# Python Regular Expression for SIP URI variables?

Tags: python, regex, expression, sip

I am using this regular expression for SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) URIs to  extract the different internal variables.

```
_syntax = re.compile('^(?P<scheme>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.]*):'  # scheme
        + '(?:(?:(?P<user>[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\!\~\*\'\(\)&=\+\$,;\?\/\%]+)' # user
        + '(?::(?P<password>[^:@;\?]+))?)@)?' # password
        + '(?:(?:(?P<host>[^;\?:]*)(?::(?P<port>[\d]+))?))'  # host, port
        + '(?:;(?P<params>[^\?]*))?' # parameters
        + '(?:\?(?P<headers>.*))?$') # headers

m = URI._syntax.match(value)
    if m: 
        self.scheme, self.user, self.password, self.host, self.port, params, headers = m.groups()
```

I need to modify this expression to support IPv6 and match all the different types of SIP URIs. The basic idea is that IPv4 shows the form 192.168.0.1 and IPv6 2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7. Beacause the port number is after :, the IPv6 is between brakets in the SIP URI.

Its general form is:

***sip:user:password@host:port;uri-parameters?headers***

These are some examples:

```
uriList = [
   'sip:192.1.2.3',
   'sip:123@192.1.2.3',
   'sip:192.1.2.3:5060',
   'sips:123@[2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7]',
   'sip:[2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7]',
   'sip:[2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7]:5060',
   'sips:support@voip.example.com',
   'sip:22444032@voip.example.com:6000',
   'sip:thks.ashwin:pass@212.123.1.213',
   ]
```

Output

```
Scheme: sip, User: , Host: 192.1.2.3, Port: 
Scheme: sip, User: 123, Host: 192.1.2.3, Port: 
Scheme: sip, User: , Host: 192.1.2.3, Port: 5060
Scheme: sips, User: 123, Host: 2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7, Port: 
Scheme: sip, User: , Host: 2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7, Port: 
Scheme: sip, User: , Host: 2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7, Port: 5060
Scheme: sips, User:support , Host: voip.example.com
Scheme: sip, User:22444032 , Host: voip.example.com, Port: 6000
Scheme: sip, User:thks.ashwin, Password:pass ,Host: 212.123.1.213
```

I tried to modify the host expression to match both [IPv6] and IPv4 expression but without luck =´(

I've been using https://pythex.org/ to test the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no headers and params in your example, so I dont know how they show up. But you can use the following code to match your example strings:

[EDIT1 - Added regex to match hostname strings and support for user:password, based on OPs new example URIs]

[EDIT2 - Added the params and headers regex and commented more on the 'OR' part of the regex]

```
import re

uriList = [
        'sip:192.1.2.3',
        'sip:123@192.1.2.3',
        'sip:192.1.2.3:5060',
        'sip:123@[2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7]',
        'sip:[2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7]',
        'sip:[2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7]:5060',
        'sips:support@voip.example.com',
        'sip:22444032@voip.example.com:6000',
        'sip:support:pass@212.123.1.213',
        'sip:support:pass@212.123.1.213;urlparams=test',
        'sip:support:pass@212.123.1.213?auth=basic',
        'sip:support:pass@212.123.1.213;urlparams=test?auth=basic',
        ]

mPattern = re.compile(
                        '(?P<scheme>\w+):' #Scheme
                        +'(?:(?P<user>[\w\.]+):?(?P<password>[\w\.]+)?@)?' #User:Password
                        +'\[?(?P<host>' #Begin group host
                            +'(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|' #IPv4 address Host Or
                            +'(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}):){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|' #IPv6 address Host Or
                            +'(?:(?:[0-9A-Za-z]+\.)+[0-9A-Za-z]+)'#Hostname string
                        +')\]?:?' #End group host
                        +'(?P<port>\d{1,6})?' #port
                        +'(?:\;(?P<params>[^\?]*))?' # parameters
                        +'(?:\?(?P<headers>.*))?' # headers
                        )
groupNamesList = ['scheme', 'user', 'password', 'host', 'port', 'params', 'headers'] #List of group Names

for uri in uriList: #iterate through the list of uri
    mObject = mPattern.search(uri) #pattern search
    if mObject: #if you find a match
        groupStrings = [mObject.group(groupName) if mObject.group(groupName) else '' for groupName in groupNamesList] #extract your groupStrings
        print('Scheme: {0}, User: {1}, Password: {2}, Host: {3}, Port: {4}, Params: {5}, Headers: {6}'.format(*groupStrings)) #print groupStrings
```

The Output I get it:

```
Scheme: sip, User: , Password: , Host: 192.1.2.3, Port: , Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: 123, Password: , Host: 192.1.2.3, Port: , Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: , Password: , Host: 192.1.2.3, Port: 5060, Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: 123, Password: , Host: 2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7, Port: , Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: , Password: , Host: 2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7, Port: , Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: , Password: , Host: 2620:0:2ef0:7070:250:60ff:fe03:32b7, Port: 5060, Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sips, User: support, Password: , Host: voip.example.com, Port: , Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: 22444032, Password: , Host: voip.example.com, Port: 6000, Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: support, Password: pass, Host: 212.123.1.213, Port: , Params: , Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: support, Password: pass, Host: 212.123.1.213, Port: , Params: urlparams=test, Headers: 
Scheme: sip, User: support, Password: pass, Host: 212.123.1.213, Port: , Params: , Headers: auth=basic
Scheme: sip, User: support, Password: pass, Host: 212.123.1.213, Port: , Params: urlparams=test, Headers: auth=basic
```

Try this out and see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks Ashwin!! this is really helpful but still need some fixes. I will add some other examples because SIP URIs are really flexible and your solution doesn't match with some. For example, the host can be a name like "voip.server.com" and a password may be added after the user. My intend was to extend just the host part to match IPv6. I see that you used a kind of "OR" expression but i am not sure how to us it to make my example to work.

Comment: @user3764940: I use https://www.debuggex.com/ to look at the flow of my regex. It gives a good pictorial view of the options. Also you can traverse through parts of your string to see what options that string has to be matched to your pattern. Meaning in this case user can either be present or not. you can traverse through example strings and see when user is caught and when user is skipped. It also gives you a view of 'OR'(|) match patterns to help you understand that better