# Sip URI validation in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation, sip

I have the following code to validate a sip:uri format string:

```
private final static Pattern SIP_URI_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(sip(?:s)?):(?:[^:]*(?::[^@]*)?@)?([^:@]*)(?::([0-9]*))?$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

public static boolean isValidURI(String address){
    if(address == null)
        return false;

    return address != null && address.length() <= 65 && SIP_URI_PATTERN.matcher(address).matches();
}
```

I'm not an expert, so I think I miss something here, when I submit this strings, it returns **true**:

***sip:4563214567@example.com***

***sip:4563214567@XX.XX.XX.XX*** -> XX = IP address

When I submit this string, it also returns true, but **should return false** because of the missing **@**:

***sip:4563214567example.com***

Any idea?

Comment: Your regex does not require the use of `@` anywhere in the string.

Comment: Yeah.  The entire input after `sip:` is matched by `([^:@]*)` because the preceding `?` makes the `@` optional.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516948/python-regular-expression-for-sip-uri-variables - This is the same question except for Python. This is a fantastic example as the answer includes test cases. The apparent work to address your question is translating the Python regex to Java.

Comment: Additional examples that might help from a tag search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sip+regex

Comment: Do you use any of the other forms for sip uris at all? (see some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516948/python-regular-expression-for-sip-uri-variables) like, ipv6 addresses, ports, querystrings, etc. You just need the `@domain` and `@ip_address` and nothing more?

Comment: yes, don't need more, thanks for your help !

Comment: The uri `sip:4563214567example.com` is a valid URI. The user part is optional.

Comment: valid SIP URI*. And don't forget you could have `sip:user:123;param=value1;param2=value2@domain` as a SIP URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think checking valid IP address or domain is more convenient in this way.

```
sip:[0-9]*@((\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b)|((([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fz77OE/4)

---

In Java form,

```
private final static Pattern SIP_URI_PATTERN =
            Pattern.compile("sip:[0-9]*@((\\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.|$)){4}\\b)|((([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})))",
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: What if `000.000.000.000`?

Comment: @Julio it's valid ip address you can check it on everywhere

Comment: Should not It be `0.0.0.0` instead?

Comment: @Julio technically there is no problem! If somewhere or some mechanism which makes it problem exist, let me know!

Comment: ok, just checking! I upvoted yours. I believe you shoud add "sips?" although. It seems to be part of OPs original regex.

Comment: thanks for the answers, when I try your regex on my java IDE, I get an "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )" message, it doesn't accept the \. escape

Comment: This is totally *not* RFC-3261 compliant for SIP URIs.

Comment: @snr If someone else comes to this question in the future because it is named "Sip URI validation in Java" and expects to use this code to validate SIP URIs, he's gonna have a really bad surprise. Answers are not only for the OP, and he did not specify anything about those SIP URIs anyway, which defaults to the RFC definition of a SIP URI.

Comment: So I was just letting any future reader know that this answer should never be used to validate any usual RFC-3261 SIP URI.

Comment: Your answer is helpful as much as sand. And good luck fixing it to be RFC-3261 compliant.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault take it and please don't comment --> https://github.com/behrad/opxiCallManager/blob/master/src/java/com/basamadco/opxi/callmanager/sip/util/SipUtil.java